# What is the purpose of this valve in my garage

Tags: water, garage, valve

Can anyone tell me the purpose of this valve in my garage
In my previous home it was in the laundry room adjacent to The garage
Is it some kind of crossover valve  between hot and cold systems?[image]

Comment: Welcome to DIY. Your guess is as good as ours. We need pictures of the other side.

Comment: the purpose of the valve is to selectively stop the flow of whatever is in the pipe

Comment: turn it off and see what stops.

Comment: It is possible that could be a main shutoff or if close to a water heater the shutoff for that.

Answer (score 4):

I had something like this in my garage where a water softener was previously.  When the water softener was removed it was easier for the previous owner to just connect the pipes instead of opening up the wall and/or rerouting the plumbing to a less noticible location.

Comment: The pipes disappear into the wall and run towards The ceiling

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. The pipes disappear into the wall and run Inside the wall up towards The ceiling.  The valve pictured  is old and corroded in position. I put a wrench on the spindle and almost broke it. I’d like to remove the whole thing as I’m trying to install a sink.  I bought a 1/4” piercing valve to check For water pressure in the pipe and there is :(   The house was built in 1970s and I’m wondering if it’s Related to The water heater nearby or perhaps the laundry Was previously in the garage. I’ve only ever seen anything like this in a laundry room at my last place